# Change the formatting of the search bar for a filtered list view

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, styling

I need to change the formatting of the search bar for a filtered list view. The blue default is pretty ugly and doesn't really look like a text input

Comment: please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `countTheme` option for listview plugin.

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.listview.prototype.options.countTheme = "a";
});
```

**[See this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-options.html)**

Comment: search bar not countTheme.

Comment: That answer has absolutely nothing to do with this question.

Comment: ye sorry guys think you were a bit off with this. Sorry my question was pretty vague

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it out, change the styling using the data-filter-theme property. I ended up setting it to b